# pandas merge with dataframes of different frequency (hourly and daily)

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I'm trying to merge dataframes that are either daily or hourly. It seems on the first iteration through my loop, I can merge the first daily with hourly values. But the second time around I get this error:

```
raise Exception('Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex')
Exception: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex
```

I can't really provide a good example, but I now that all the dataframes are tz-aware when they are created (e.g. I call `df.tz_localize('UTC')` on each after it is created.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to make your frames non-timezone aware (timezone unaware?). Maybe

```
df_no_tz = df.copy()
df_no_tz.index.tz = None
```

I don't know, but it sounds like something in `pandas` is either creating a frame without a timezone, or removing your timezone information. Making the frames timezone agnostic may fix this (if this is what it is, implying this is a bug in `pandas`).

Comment: In newer versions you need to use `df.index.tz_convert(None)`

Comment: For me I am using pandas==1.1.5, all the above don't work, I need to do:  
`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` then 
`df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)`